# Oracle APEX Javascript - docViewer not working in Firefox when replacing current pdf with new pdf

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have docViewer implemented in my app to upload and replacing pdfs.
There are no issues in Chrome or Edge however to show the updated pdf I have to either log out/log into the application again or right click and 'Reload Frame' in Firefox.

In the Firefox console I have been getting these messages:
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.
Partitioned cookie or storage access was provided to “URL” because it is loaded in the third-party context and dynamic state partitioning is enabled.

Here is the code followed by the UI.

```
$('#docViewer').html('');
var url = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:93:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=RENDER_DOC::::';
var preview = document.createElement('embed'); 
preview.type = "application/pdf";
preview.width="100%";
preview.height="625px";
preview.src = url;
$("#docViewer").append(preview);
preview.src = url;
```

```
function resume(){
   $('#docViewer').html('');
   var url = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:93:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=RENDER_DOC::::';
    
   var preview = document.createElement('embed'); 
   preview.type = "application/pdf";
   preview.width="100%";
   preview.height="625px";
   preview.src = url;
   const hasStorageAccess = document.hasStorageAccess().then((result) => {
     console.log(`hasStorageAccess: ${result}`);
   });
   $("#docViewer").append(preview);
   preview.src = url;
}
```

[image]

I've tried various properties and cannot figure it out.